# how to send string list from controller to javascript (present in view) in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In this controller i got all the movienames

```
public ActionResult MultiText()
 {
    List<string> mnames = db.AllMovienames().ToList();
    ViewBag.movies = mnames;

    return View();
}
```

I need to send this "ViewBag.movies" to Javascript present in view

```
 $(function () {

    var availableTags = ViewBag.movies;
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind("keydown", function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
   $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

But i cant get values into view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it out as json in your view like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var movies =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.movies))
</script>
```

If you wrap your javascript up into a function you could then pass them in i.e.

```
function DoThis(movies)
{
   var availableTags = movies;
    .....
}
```

This would allow you to call it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var movies =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.movies))
 DoThis(movies);
</script>
```

Comment: it show compile time error.is there any assembly i need to give?

Comment: System.Web.Helpers.Json is the assembly

Answer (score 0):

You could put the tags into a hidden field and then retrieve them using jQuery:

View:

```
 @Html.Hidden("Movies", string.Join(",", ViewBag.movies))
```

JavaScript:

```
 var availableTags = $('#Movies').val().split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below：

```
/In Controller

/Controller/SiteConfig
public ActionResult SiteConfig()
{
     string movie = // your code
     return JavaScript("var movies ="+moive);
}
//In cshtml
@Script.Render("~/Controller/SiteConfig")
```

Then you can get variable movie in javascript.